# Removing a node from a linked list with "del" doesn't work

Tags: python

The problematic part is in the function `remove`. Even after `del` is called, the relevant node is not removed from the Linked List. Did I misunderstand something about `del`?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None

    def add(self, val):
        if not (self.next):
            self.next = Node(val)
        else:
            self.next.add(val)

    def remove(self, val):
        if self.val == val:
            if self.next:
                self.val = self.next.val
                self.next = self.next.next
            else:
                del self # this doesn't remove the node from linked list

        else:
            if self.next:
                self.next.remove(val)
            else:
                print "no such val found %d" % val

    def __str__(self):
        output = []
        while self is not None:
            output.append(str(self.val))
            self = self.next
        return " -> ".join(output)


head = Node(1)
head.add(2)
print head
head.remove(3)
head.add(3)
head.add(4)
print head
head.remove(3)
head.remove(4)
print head
```

Comment: `del` removes a name from the local namespace, in effect "undefining" a variable or dict key. It has no earthly idea how to work with your custom linked list implementation. You'll have to provide your own mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `del self` only removes the name `self` from the local scope (and decrements the reference count).  It has no effect on the other references to it nor to those objects.

To remove the node from the linked list, you must update the node(s) that refer to it.  Since you have a singly linked list, you must traverse the list from the beginning to find the node whose `node.next == self`, then change it to `node.next = self.next` to remove self from the sequence of links.

Comment: If the only thing that distinguishes two nodes is the data they carry and the link to the next node, then you can "delete" the current node by replacing its data and link with that of the next node. No need to fully traverse the list. If this is a satisfactory definition of "delete" (and can be extended to deal with the last node), then you can implement `__del__` on the class so that `del Node` does what one would expect.

Comment: neither ```del``` nor ```__del__``` are intended for that purpose.

Comment: @ChadSimmons I suppose you're right. By the time `__del__` is called, nothing will be referring to the node anyway, so updating it is pointless. But my main point about removing a node from a linked list not requiring traversal stands.